# Node.js submit span values to controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, form-submit

How can I send the text values from `span` tags to a controller?

user_profile.hbs

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">User Profile</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/home/user/profile/update">
      <div>
        Username: <span id="user_upd">{{user}}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        Email: <span id="email_upd">{{email}}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        Type: <span>{{type}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Update Info"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

userController.js

```
// Display User update form on GET
module.exports.userUpdateGet = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.render('user_profile_update', {
    usename: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    user: req.user.username
  });  
}
```

And this is the `user_profile_update` view:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Update User</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/home/user/profile/update">
      <div>
        <label for="username">Username: </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value={{username}}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="email">Email: </label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value={{email}}/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

My goal is to display the information from `user_profile.hbs` as input values to `user_profile_update.hbs`.

EDIT:

I tried to use this `js` code, but the `user_profile_update` view is not rendered ... why?

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var user,email;
    $("#submit_update").click(function(){
      user= $("#user_upd").text();
      email= $("#email_upd").text();
      $.get("/user/profile/update", {user: user,email: email}, function(data){
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">User Profile</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/home/user/profile/update">
      <div>
        Username: <span>{{user}}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        Email: <span>{{email}}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        Type: <span>{{type}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Update Info"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Change this to

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">User Profile</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/home/user/profile/update">
      <input type="hidden" name="user" value={{user}}/>
      <input type="hidden" name="email" value={{email}}/>
      <input type="hidden" name="type" value={{type}}/>
      <div>
        Username: <span>{{user}}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        Email: <span>{{email}}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        Type: <span>{{type}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Update Info"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

You can use [input hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) or when form onclick you can use js to set cookie & then retrieve the cookie from server

Comment: I would better like to use js, but it doesn't render the expected view. Would you please check the code from my updated answer?